# I am building my first "Hello World" project with Codelite but am getting this error: "No such file or directory. Any ideas?

Tags: c++, macos, codelite

When I open up the file (saved on my desktop) I see the workspace I created, the project created within the workspace and main.cpp within the project. The only error that comes to mind might be my username which includes an underscore. Is there a way to save my file without including my username? I am using Codelite version 13.0 on my Mac. Thanks.

MacBook-Pro% /tmp/codelite-exec.sh ; exit;
/tmp/codelite-exec.sh: line 3: /Users/Rodpod_Barnacle/Desktop/Cplusplus/FirstWorkspace/Project1/Debug/Project1: No such file or directory

It turns out the issue *was* the underscore in my home directory account name. I ended up changing it and my program compiled. If you need directions on how to change your home directory name just google "Change the name of your account MacOS user account and home folder."

Comment: Does `/Users/Rodpod_Barnacle/Desktop/Cplusplus/FirstWorkspace/Project1/Debug/Project1` exist?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes it does! I created the Cplusplus folder before I started the project. Saved it on my desktop. I created firstworkspace then project1 within that workspace. I don't know why I am receiving this error. Right now I am attempting to change my home directory name so it does not include an underscore. That is the only thing I can think of.